# NodeJS writeFileSync The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object

Tags: node.js, file

Hello I'm studying mqtt file transfer with node js 
and I got this error message

```
Uncaught TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object
```

executing the code below

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');
var fs = require('fs');
 
client.on('connect', function () {
      client.subscribe('cws');
});
 
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
      data = JSON.parse(message);
      fs.writeFileSync(data.name, data.data);
      client.end();
});
```

but the node.js document says 
data argument could be string, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, Object
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the `data` object you get from `JSON.parse(message)` contains a nested object also called `data`.  If you want to save that to a file you have to serialize it into JSON or some other string-like format.

```
fs.writeFileSync(data.name, JSON.stringify(data.data))
```

**BEWARE!** if some cybercreep manages to send you this `message` your code may wreck your Linux operating system. (Similar messages can wreck Windows and Mac OSs too.) Check the values of those `name` attributes you get in your messages as if your business depended on it, because it does.

```
{ name: '/boot/vmlinuz',
  data: 'all your OS are belong to us!' }
```